# Jquery not recognizing a clicked button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble with jquery with regards to the `click()` method. I have the following code:

```
text += "<input type='button' id='create_setup_button' value='Add SetUp' />";
text += "<input type='button' id='create_teardown_button' value='Add Teardown' />";
text += "<input type='button' id='create_event_button' value='Create Event' />";

$("#create_setup_button").click(function () {
    alert("what is good?");
});
```

Is there something I am missing that is causing the button not to click? Cheers ~

Comment: bcoz you are generating `#create_setup_button` dynamically use event delegation...`$(document.body).on('click','#create_setup_button',function(){....});`

Comment: Did you add `text` to the DOM? From your code it seems you did not...

Comment: Thanks, that worked - would you mind explaining why event delegation needs to be used when a button is created dynamically?

Comment: no plalx, I did not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is clearly not all your code.  What happens to the text variable?  when does it go in the dom?

If your click handler comes before putting text in the dom, then it will not work because you click handler can not find the element at time of execution.

If you use:

```
$('body').on('click', '#create_setup_button', function () {
    alert("what is good?");
});
```

it should work because you have an event delegate on the body that will trap all bubbling click events on elements that match the `#create_setup_button` selector.

Answer (score 2):

Because your buttons are dynamically added with the js code you should use event delegation **[`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** to deal with fresh DOM :

```
$("body").on('click','#create_setup_button', function () {
    alert("what is good?");
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The target is dynamically created.

You need to delegate the event to the target

```
$("body").on('click', '#create_setup_button',function (event) {
            alert("what is good?");
        });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q6b1czv9/)